# Can we charachterize spheres by the symmetricity?

Tags: differential-geometry

$n\geq2$. $c\in\mathbb{R}$.

Given an orthogonal basis $(e_i)_{i=1}^n$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a hyperplane $P=\{y^1e_1+\cdots+y^{n-1}e_{n-1}+ce_n\ |\ y^1,\cdots,y^{n-1}\in\mathbb{R}\}$ in it, we define the reflection $\Phi_P:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ by $\Phi_P(y^1e_1+\cdots+y^{n-1}e_{n-1}+y^ne_n):=y^1e_1+\cdots+y^{n-1}e_{n-1}+(2c-y^n)e_n$.

Suppose $M$ be a closed connected orientable submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ of $n-1$ dimensional. Then is it true that *if $\forall p\in S^{n-1}:=\{|x|=1\}$ $\exists c\in\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $\Phi_{\langle p\rangle^\perp+cp}(M)\subset M$ holds, $M$ is a sphere* ?

Comment: You should restrict to only $c=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Orthogonal group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_group) can be generated by reflections. So if $p\in M$, the sphere $S(p)=\{x : |x|=|p|\}\subset M$. If there is another point $q\in M-S(p)$, then $S(q)\subset M$. But M is connected, so there is a path from $p$ to $q$. By continuity all points between $S(p)$ and $S(q)$ belongs to M, which contradicts the fact that $M$ is of $n-1$ dimensional.